# Network provider generates a 2 copies of a location

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation

I'm trying to generate a location first through the gps provider if I get a null I'm generating through the network provider.
My problem is that the network provider generates the same location twice.. I send the information to the db and it sends the same location with the same time(same seconds!).
Here is some code:

```
gpsLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, R.string.not_support_gps);
networkLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, R.string.not_support_gps);
    // Update the UI immediately if a location is obtained.
if (gpsLocation != null) 
    updateUILocation(gpsLocation);
else
    updateUILocation(networkLocation);
```

Here is the requestUpdateFromProvider:

```
private Location requestUpdatesFromProvider(final String provider, final int errorResId) 
{
    Location location = null;
    if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) 
    {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEN_SECONDS, TEN_METERS*2, listener);
        location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    } 
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, errorResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return location;
}
```

Here is the updateUILocation:

```
private void updateUILocation(Location location) 
{
    // We're sending the update to a handler which then updates the UI with the new location.
    Message.obtain(mHandler,
            UPDATE_LATLNG,
            location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude()).sendToTarget();

    // Bypass reverse-geocoding only if the Geocoder service is available on the device.
    if (mGeocoderAvailable) 
        doReverseGeocoding(location);
}
```

Here is the handler:

```
    mHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            if(msg.what == UPDATE_ADDRESS) //UPDATE_ADDRESS = 1
            {
                LocationService.this.address = (String) msg.obj; // update a string that show the user address
                new SendLocation(LocationService.this.id,(String)msg.obj);//send the info to the db.
            }
        }
    };
```

The SendLocation is doing what it suppose to do correctly so you shouldn't pay attention to it.

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that the first piece of code is a method called from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If its not your fault that dupplicate locations are created, then just call a syncronized `forwardLocation(Location loc)` method, that stored the timestamp of the last received location.
This methods shall ignore a location when its last stored timestamp is equal to the previous one.